# Omniauth-facebook rails 3 => invalid credentials error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

I am using omniauth-facebook gem in my rails app to authenticate with facebook.
Everything worked fine, but recently i have "invalid credentials" error in my production server. (in local it still works great).

I've read that it is due to the last version of the gem (1.4.1) and downgrading to 1.4.0 should solve the problem.
But it does not work for me and i don't know where to look.

ps: i have rails 3.2.11

Thanks for you help.

Comment: do you have already created a facebook application for production and the right setup in your config.yml file or where ever you save your tokens?

Comment: I am running into the exact same issue. Was working fine, now it's not.

Comment: 1) How are you storing your credentials (keys) 2) are you using Heroku?  some code from your current setup would help so that we can diagnose whats going on.. could be anything at this stage as we dont know whats going on

Comment: I am using heroku and i have an omniauth.rb file in initializers where i store my credentials

Comment: Have you set the correct App Domains in your Facebook app settings?